# SED Ensure XML insert not inside comment

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am working with stock RHEL7/8 tools, and writing a script that will add a piece to a config file that is formatted as XML. I have run into a case where my `sed` statement can insert the added text inside a comment.

My current `sed` command gets the last existence of the tag `<Program>` and inserts the new tag after its closing tag `</Program>`.

How can I account for this possibly, but not always being inside a comment?

My script:

```
sed -i '0,/<Program id/s// <Program id=\"myProgram\"> <\/Program>' filepath
```

XML Example (displays the error inserting inside comment):

```
<Program id="myProgram"></Program>

<!-- 
<Program id="commentedOutProgram"></Program>
<Program id="newlyAddedProgram"><Program>
-->
```

**EDIT:**
This is happening at install time. I would like to add a way for some RHEL 7/8 built in tool to look in the `XML file`, make sure it's not in a comment, and add the new contents

Comment: You would be better off using a specialised XML parser such as xmllint or xmlstarlet

Comment: @RamanSailopal is xml lint on all RHEL7/8 Systems? If it is, I could look into using that instead

Comment: It should be available yes.

Comment: @Raman Sailopal xml lint seems to not be able to be used for adding elements to XML, I do not have xmlstarlet and cannot add it to the system, there are restrictions in place that prevent new dependencies

Comment: @Cyrus I cannot add new dependencies.

Comment: How about Python? How about Perl? Using a language which ships with an XML library is going to be _hugely_ more robust than trying to force fit a line-oriented regex tool to this task.

Comment: @triplee this is happening at install time of the software, Python probably will not work for this application, I am unfamiliar with perl so I'm not sure about it's use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with this. The usual caveats apply: It probably only works for *exactly* the sample you provided. Use a proper XML tool if you need a robust solution.

```sh
sed -e '/<!--/,/-->/b' \
    -e '0,\%<Program id="[^"]*"></Program>%s%<Program id="myProgram"> </Program>%' filepath
```

Your original script seemed to have several errors, so I couldn't copy it verbatim, but this should at least give you an idea of how to modify it: add a `b` to skip any lines between `<!--` and `-->`.

The `%` separators are just to avoid having to backslash slashes; `sed` allows you to use any separator you like instead of a slash, you just have to backslash the first one.

The `b` command jumps to a label; if the label is not specified, it jumps to the end of the script, i.e. skips the substitution part and starts over with the next line.  The address expression before `b` selects any comment region, i.e. any lines between a line matching `<!--` and a line matching `-->`.

Comment: Could you give a more in depth explanation for each piece? This seems to be the correct solution, I'm just struggling to grasp what is happening. Also, what are the % symbols doing?

Comment: Updated with a brief explanation.

Comment: I did end up having to split the statements. `sed '/<!--/,/-->/b' -e '0,/Program id/s//<!--test text-->\n filename.xml` this replaces the occurrence of `<Program>` before the comment block but it's close enough I can take it from here. Thank you!

Comment: You still seem to be lacking the final separator in the `s//../`

Comment: Sorry, it's there in my actual statement. `...\n/' filename.xml`

Comment: Scratch my comment where I had it working.... I found an error print out `sed: can't read /<!--/,/-->/b: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you use `-e`, you need an `-e` before that one too. I have updated the answer to demonstrate this.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee ! I now have a working sed statement:)